# sh: java: permission denied tryinng to execute .jar file

Tags: java, linux

My OS: SLiTaz 32 bits, last version.
I installed java in /usr/bin/java/jre-8u171-i586

I run the terminal as root, cd to where my executable jar file is, and type:

## java -jar desktop-1.7.2a-1.jar

I get:

sh: java: Permission denied

What is the cause of this and how can I execute my .jar file?

Also know that this file is a game, more specifically "Pixel Dungeon".

Edit: when I execute java -version, it again says permission denied. I must say that to execute these commands, I run the terminal as my own user, Flavius, then do su, enter password and from there I execute all commands.

Edit2: To install java I uncompressed the tar.gz file I got from the official java site using a website, because I didn't know how to uncompress it by commands, then I moved java files to /usr/bin and then I tried just double clicking the .jar file to execute it, but it asked what program to use to execute .jar files, and I didn't know how to fin java in that menu so I tried using commands...

Comment: Does the user with which you operate has the right to run the file.

Comment: What happens when you execute 'java -version'?

Comment: Why do you run it as root?  And how did you install java?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu and how can I enable that permission? I am thinking of reinstalling java.

Comment: Why are you not installing Java with your distros's package manager?

Answer (score 0):

It seeem that **java** binary does not have execution permission.  Executing **chmod a+x /usr/bin/java/jre-8u171-i586/bin/java** might solve the issue.

But it something wrong about how you installed java. I would try to install it using the [package manager](http://doc.slitaz.org/en:handbook:packages).

Comment: Done, permission denied, reinstalling java.

Comment: Execute it with root permissions.

Comment: Reinstalled java, executed everything with root permissions, "Permission denied"

Comment: I tried using taz package manager, it says "failed" after the "Installing package" step.  I guess it is not compatible.

Comment: @EmanuelHongu same here it seems to be specific to slitaz